# 64-bit version of DLL crashes on memory free; 32-bit does not

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, 32bit-64bit, dll

I've coded a program in C that uses the NX Open C library.  I have to compile it into a .dll, and as a 32-bit .dll on a 32-bit machine, it works beautifully.  However, when I put the same code in Visual Studio on a 64-bit machine and specify that it compile for 64-bit, and I run the program, it crashes on a line that frees some memory.  When I comment out that line for the 64-bit version, it runs fine.  The NX Open documentation indicates that this is memory I'm supposed to free.

**My question is this:** What causes this?  Why does a program, coded exactly the same, crash on a memory free in its 64-bit version on a 64-bit machine, and not the 32-bit version on a 32-bit machine?  Is this something I should have expected? Have I done something wrong that I can prevent?  Or is it a symptom of a bigger problem?

**Version info:** I'm using Visual Studio 2005, NX 5.0.6.3, Windows XP SP3

Comment: For any crash, you need to check call stack at crash (exception, such as access violation) position. The cause other than a bug in code, details depend on exception details.

Comment: There are all sorts of possible explanations for this but the most likely is that you have cast a pointer to a 32 bit integer and thus truncated it. You'll need to narrow it down a bit before we can help much more specifically.

Comment: Thanks...I'll add more information as I acquire it, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a memory corruption bug of some sort. You either:

- deallocate the same memory twice
- work with already freed memory (thereby corrupting new memory allocations)
- write outside the allocated memory (thereby corrupting other allocations or the memory management structures)

It's likely that the bug exists in the 32-bit version as well but hasn't been discovered yet because it never damaged essential data.

It can be very hard to find such a bug. I therefore recommend using a memory debugger such as Purify, Valgrind or Insure++ to detect where the problematic memory accesses are.

Comment: I've started looking at the problem from this standpoint, and found that the NX library has a special UF_free() function that I'm supposed to use instead of a regular free().  So far, it seems like it might fix the problem, but I'm going to keep looking to see if I'm missing something else.

Comment: It was the fact that I didn't use UF_free() in this case, which implies there's some memory management that's specific to NX going on in that function.  It was an issue in both 32-bit and 64-bit, as far as I can tell, even though it didn't present itself in the 32-bit version.